# Blender for Mac 2.9.1 can't find edge vertex face select buttons

Tags: edit-mode

I'm brand new to Blender(Mac). Every link I follow to find the three selection type buttons says they're located just to the right of the Object/Edit mode button, but not on my interface:

[image]

Can anyone help, please?

TIA

**Edit:**

Seems like a number of things will make the buttons appear: Quitting, restarting Blender: Changing workspaces, then changing back. Annoying, but seems to work...

Comment: Strange, but to be fair, once you start using the shortcuts (number keys 1, 2, 3), you'll probably never use the selection boxes again. They're a lot easier anyway. I know it doesn't solve your problem, but I don't think it's the worst inconvenience in the end, unless other features are missing as well.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett--I'm a huge fan of keyboard shortcuts, but nothing happens when I press those keys. Is there a modifier key on the Mac?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to edit a curve, not a mesh object.

**They are different kind of objects**, the menus change depending on the context. Curves have no vertices or faces.

Take a minute to read the manual (not a video) to understand the difference.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/types.html

For curves:

[image]

For meshes

[image]

Comment: @susu--
I've used Maya in the past, so have a general understanding of the difference between Mesh and Curve. But I'm brand new to Blender, and the way it handles each type, so I guess I didn't know what I had selected. Thanks very much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a 2.9 Mac issue.  I am still using Blender 2.83 for Mac and they show up as normal, to the right of edit mode.